# Function in JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, function, object

```
var stack_1 = 
       {
          sp: 10,
          stk: new Array(10),

          push: function (v)
          { 
            sp = sp - 1; 
            stk[sp] = v; 
          }
    }
```

Question :

This program does not work. Because we need to write "this.sp" etc. I dont understand why we need to write "this.sp" if the function totally belongs to "stack_1".

Comment: `this` depends on how the function is being called, not on where it is defined.

Comment: that's how javascript works - unlike c# for example, it doesn't "assume" you want `this` context for whatever you are accessing

Comment: As long as a variable is in the local scope, there's no need to use `this.variable`, unless of course there is an identically-named variable outside the object, but accessible from inside the object.

Comment: I was thinking that since the function "push" belongs to "stack_1", "push" should be able to access everything of "stack_1".

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` refers to the **current object** that is `stack_1` in your example. And sp,stk are the properties of `stack_1` but not of push function. That is why you need to use `this.sp` to denote that you're using `sp` property of the `stack_1` object.

This is how JavaScript works.

Comment: Hey,
I was thinking that since the function "push" belongs to "stack_1", "push" should be able to access everything of "stack_1".

Answer (score 0):

Context is most often determined by how a function is invoked. When a function is called as a method of an object, `this` is set to the object the method is called on,
example :

```
var obj = {
foo: function(){
    alert(this === obj);    
}
};

obj.foo(); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

`sp` and `stk` are not variables, they're object properties. And properties have to be accessed relative to a specific object.

You can change the function to use `stack_1.sp` and `stack_1.stk`, to access the properties of that object.

Or you can use `this.sp` and `this.stk`. When you use `this`, you have to call the function as `stack_1.push()`, because the special variable `this` is only set automatically when you call a function relative to a specific object.

This may seem redundant for your simple case, but it makes sense when you use prototypes or inheritance. In that case, multiple objects can share the same function, and it needs to know which object to operate on. The mechanism of setting `this` is the same in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

one thing that's worth noting is that you can change the context / `this` inside the function setting it explicitly with `call` or `apply`:

```js
var stack_1 = {
  sp: 10,
  stk: new Array(10),

  push:function (v)  {
    this.sp = this.sp - 1;
    this.stk[this.sp] = v;
    console.log(this)
  }
}

var stack_2 ={
  sp: 22,
  stk: new Array(20)
}

stack_1.push(42)
console.log(stack_1.stk)

stack_1.push.call(stack_2,55)
console.log(stack_2.stk)
```